# Mathematically modelling a dataset

Tags: machine-learning, regression, mathematical-modeling, data-analysis, python

I am trying to construct a model/mathematical equation to describe a behaviour supplied by a dataset. The data itself, looks like it has a very particular relationship but I don't really know how to approach fitting a curve to it. Do I start off with linear and progress to polynomial regression techniques? Do I just randomly try out different types of functions using trial-end-error to see if it works out fine? For example I have the dataset plotted below and I suspect it resembles some kind of Bessel function or damped sine wave. How do I fit a curve onto it with the right parameters in Python or MATLAB? How do I even confirm that a Bessel function works well?[image]

Comment: Only from practical experience: 1) You have a big uncorrelated blob of data in the middle. Maybe extent your analysis and look for possible variables describing blob. 2) You might be able to fit two functions upper and lower bound to envelope data blob. Finding functions is the 'easy' part: linking to physical meaning is difficult. Maybe focus on physics first and describe what you see. 3) Do not remain staring blindly at this plot alone and make allot different plots with more variables looking at title windspeed I came up with: time, season, temperature etc. to describe what you see.

Comment: To find missing variable one can use matrix plots.: Python: https://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/scatterplot_matrix.html#scatterplot-matrix . Matlab: https://www.mathworks.com/help/econ/corrplot.html. When you find missing variable you might be able to find fit function.